# Scrapy twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return: Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Hey i am newbie to scrapy and just wrote my first ScrawlSpider.But i am getting this exception over and over again

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/afraz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
>     packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1301, in _inlineCallbacks
>     result = g.send(result)
>     File "/home/afraz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
>     packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in 
>     process_request
>     defer.returnValue((yield 
>     download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
>     File "/home/afraz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
>     packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1278, in returnValue
>     raise _DefGen_Return(val)
>     twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return: <200 
>     http://www.kmart.com.au/product/plain-crew-tee/855808>
>     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Here is my code

```
def parse_category(self, response):
    print("inside parse_catagory with url {}".format(response.url))

    urls_to_extract = LinkExtractor(deny=r"javascript",
                                  restrict_css=
     ('div[id="resultcontent"]'
                                                '> div'),
                                  ).extract_links(response)

    urls_to_visit = [url_to_extract.url for url_to_extract in 
   urls_to_extract]
    for url in urls_to_visit:
        return scrapy.Request(url, callback="parse_item", meta=
   {"parent_url": response.url})

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = KmartItem()
    item.description = self.get_description(response)
    item.url = response.url
    item.gender = self.get_gender(response)
    item.name = response.css('h1[itemprop="name"] 
    ::text').extract_first()
    item.category = self.get_category(response)
    item.image_urls = response.css('img[id="productMainImage"] 
    ::attr(src)').extract()
    item.product_id = response.css('span[class="sku"] 
    ::text').extract_first()

    yield item

def get_gender(self, response):

    parent_url = response.meta["parent_url"]
    category_substr = re.compile("category.*").findall(parent_url)
    gender = category_substr[0].split('/')[1]

    if gender is not "men" and gender is not "women":
        gender = ("boy" if "boy" in parent_url else
                  "girl" if "girl" in parent_url else
                  "unisex children")

    return gender
```

I want to save outut in a json file lease help :)

Comment: Can you provide the whole traceback and logs for the crawl? What version of scrapy are you using? (output of `scrapy version -v` is always helpful) Are you using any middleware?

Comment: Scrapy    : 1.3.3  
lxml      : 3.7.2.0
libxml2   : 2.9.4
cssselect : 1.0.1
parsel    : 1.1.0
w3lib     : 1.17.0
Twisted   : 17.1.0
Python    : 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) - ]
pyOpenSSL : 16.2.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)
Platform  : Linux-4.8.0-52-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid

Comment: What about the full traceback and scrapy crawl logs?

Comment: stackoverflow is not allowing me to pyt here that is too long string

Comment: You can use a pastebin service or GitHub gist for example.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/afrazahmad21/70dd7239f4809be236a7708be028c30a

Comment: please see code here https://gist.github.com/afrazahmad21/adb9f71a3cb83661a5bc3c0c0d2ba268

Comment: What about crawl log? When scrapy starts, it prints middleware and extension and all. You havent answered that

Comment: Can you try with `callback=self.parse_item` in parse_category?

Comment: Thank you @paul God bless you :) It worked

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, I've opened [an issue on Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2766) so that passing a string would be valid, or at least make the exception more actionable.